# MultiRowUpdate in application Express (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

when you work with a tabular form in Apex (application express, Oracle) you have automatic process for a MULTI ROW UPDATE and MULTI ROW DELETE.

I'm interested in seeing the code behind these processes.

Can anyone tell me where I can see them?

Thanks.

Patrick

Comment: Hello Patrick and Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that [StackOverflow already adds a signature for you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) so you shouldn't add one manually.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the code, since it will be in one of the APEX packages, and these are wrapped.
However it will probably resemble the sort of code you would have to write yourself using the apex_item package etc.  There are tutorials for this around if you search for "oracle apex create tabular form manually" - for example [this YouTube-based tutorial](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=13477790.8).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must look this thread. Code of built-in multi-row update process is similar.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2459200